# Record Audio using Custom Keyboard Extension in iOS (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, avfoundation

**I am trying to record audio from a record button inside Keyboards View and then play it back to the user with the play button but neither its recording nor it is playing the audio.**

Xcode Version: 13.2.1

Here is the error:
[Screenshot of Error when the record button is tapped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbzJx.png)

**Below is my code for recording and playing the audio:**

```
class AudioRecoder: NSObject, AVAudioRecorderDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

var recordingSession: AVAudioSession!
var audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder!
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

func askPermission() {
    recordingSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    do {
        try recordingSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default)
        try recordingSession.setActive(true)
        recordingSession.requestRecordPermission() { [unowned self] allowed in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if allowed {
                    print("user has allowed")
                } else {
                    print("user has not allowed")
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        // failed to record!
        print("failed to record!")
    }
}

func playSound() throws {
    let url = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("recording.m4a")
    audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    audioPlayer.play()
}

func startRecording() {
    let audioFilename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("recording.m4a")

    let settings = [
        AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
        AVSampleRateKey: 12000,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
    ]

    do {
        audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: audioFilename, settings: settings)
        audioRecorder.delegate = self
        audioRecorder.record()

        //recordButton.setTitle("Tap to Stop", for: .normal)
    } catch {
        finishRecording(success: false)
    }
}

func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    return paths[0]
}

func finishRecording(success: Bool) {
    audioRecorder.stop()
    audioRecorder = nil

    if success {
        //recordButton.setTitle("Tap to Re-record", for: .normal)
    } else {
        //recordButton.setTitle("Tap to Record", for: .normal)
        // recording failed :(
    }
}

func recordTapped() {
    if audioRecorder == nil {
        startRecording()
    } else {
        finishRecording(success: true)
    }
}

func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(_ recorder: AVAudioRecorder, successfully flag: Bool) {
    if !flag {
        finishRecording(success: false)
    }
}}
```

Comment: This isn't SwiftUI

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working correctly actually. I just put your code into an example project and it worked fine.

Make sure you added Microphone Usage Description to Info.plist and I would suggest putting some logs in the code to understand your issue. For example:

- What getDocumentsDirectory() method returns in your case?
- At which point of the code you receive this error?

Also you can download the container and check in the Documents directory whether it is actually saving the audio file.

[image: Download Container]

Comment: It worked fine on a Simulator, but error when running on a device. Can you try it on an actual device?

Comment: I only tested this with an actual device and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/keyboards_and_input/creating_a_custom_keyboard/configuring_open_access_for_a_custom_keyboard), custom keyboards do not have no access to microphone and speaker. You cannot directly use microphone from your keybaord extension app.
There is a workaround, you can initiate audio recording from your containing app and pass the speech-to-text 'text' to the keyboard extension.

[image]

Any extension app will have these 3 components.

- **Containing app** is the main app for any extension. This app and the extension are bundled and installed to the device all together. The primary function of the containing app is to deliver an extension to the user. When your app is installed on a device and your extension is registered in the system (which is done automatically by iOS) your extension is delivered and ready for user to use it.
- **App Extension** is the actual extension that will be used by the host app, e.g custom keyboard or share extension
- **Host app** is the app which runs your extension, in which context the extension works. Third party apps, system apps or even some parts of iOS itself may be the “host app”. In our case (Custom Keyboard Extension) every app which has input text field can be a host app.

So basically, when you click on the MIC button on custom keybaord, open the  containing app with URL Scheme, start recording, come back to host app (recording will be ON in backgorund) and dictate. The dication will be processed in containing app and passed/shared to keyboard extension.

Download the Google's GBoard keybaord or Microsoft's SwiftKey keyboard from  App Store to see it working.

Comment: Hey, that's very helpful, thanks. Do you know how to go back to the host app?

Comment: I have same question as @Yotam. How to go back to host app from Containing app?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76469803/swiftui-ios-app-how-to-navigate-back-from-containing-app-to-host-app

Comment: The documentation you linked specifically states that you can have access to microphone if you enable full access

Comment: I have tried that option. It kind of works, but UX not very smooth. 
It is because when "containing app" closes itself and you go back to "host app", your keyboard already closed (it closes automatically once "host app" loses focus). So user had to tap on text field again, so your keyboard is open again and can insert recognised text.  But it seems there is no workaround, because gboard also have that problem.